# modify an instance's propriety directly in flash(not in actionscript)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flash-component

If i create a movieclip named player and in this class there is the proprety map
(a string) and level(an int);
I would like to know if there is a way of modifying these propreties without actionscript when i create an instance of that symbol.
For exemple, like you would modify the height and the width of a movieclip in flash(the program, not actionscript), but modify this instance's map and level proprieties instead

Thank you for yor help!

Comment: The only way I can think of is to link a class to the MovieClip and make it a component and use the [Inspectable] metadata tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a custom component then you can use the component inspector to access any variables you need to. Of course there is some  work involved with making a custom component, including coding it beforehand, but once you have it built then you can access instances via the GUI like you are describing.

The other option would be to simply handle it with Actionscript, which in my opinion would be an easier route.